# 3-value logic: do these laws of thought apply?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

[Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) explains Kleene’s three value logic truth tables, but is not clear on what happens to the *Law of the Excluded Middle* $\vdash p \lor \lnot p$ and *Non-Contradiction* $\vdash \lnot (p \land \lnot p)$. Does anyone know how these concepts carry over with 3VL?

I considered using the Kleene truth tables for the above, but the $\vdash$ operator is 2VL for its argument.

Answer (score 4):

They don't apply, because as Wikipedia says, $K_3$ has no tautologies because if all propositional variables have the unknown value, the formula as a whole receives the unknown value, which makes it not valid.

Just take $p$ as unknown and do the truth tables and you'll see that not all values can be true.

Comment: No tautologies, implies the two laws in OP do not apply?  Also what do you mean by valid formulas?  I formed expressions which appear valid according 3VL rules and database systems use Kleene's 3VL in SQL quesi-1st order logic predicate formulas, which are valid.

Comment: Yes, it means both of them don't apply. Valid formulas are theorems, which in propositional calculus are the same thing as tautologies. I'll edit that out since it probably just makes the answer more confusing. $K_3$ has no tautologies because if all propositional variables have the unknown value, the formula as a whole receives the unknown value, which makes it not valid.

Comment: Check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1470933) answer out.